# Deserializing a random derived class of a known superclass

Tags: java, serialization, inheritance

I'm new to serialization, so this might be a simple question, but my google-fu is weak today.

Suppose you have the following classes:

```
public class Base implements Serializable {
    // ...
}

public class Der1 extends Base {
    // ...
}

public class Der2 extends Base {
    // ...
}
```

Alice randomly creates an object of either `Der1` or `Der2`, serializes it to a file, and sends it to Bob. Bob knows this object's class is a subclass of `Base`, but doesn't know which one (he has the same class definitions that Alice has). How can Bob deserialize the file to be an instance of the proper subclass?

My first thought was that Alice could define a class like this:

```
public DerClass implements Serializable {
    public Class<? extends Base> class;
}
```

She uses this to store the object's class, serializes it and sends it to Bob. Bob constructs a `DerClass` object from this file, reads the `class` variable, uses it to instantiate the proper subclass, and reads the serialized object into it. Would this work? Is there a better way?

Comment: I always wonder were people get these "random classes" from. What's the actual situation here? Your serialized format has to contain some information to identify itself in any case.

Comment: @suszterpatt: I think if you write the code for Bob here as well, your question would be more SO friendly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The deserializing application doesn't need to know the type, it only needs to have the same class available in the class path.  e.g. Alice need to have all the classes Bob might send and their parents and dependants.

```
// Bob sends
Base base = // some Base class
objectOutputStream.writeObjec(base);

// Alice receives
Base base = (Base) objectInputStream.readObject();
```

Comment: But this way, Alice does not get to know the derived type of `base`. She might  want to use the actual derived type `Der1` or `Der2`. How would one solve that issue?

Comment: @JonasGröger She can do `if (base instanceof Der1) { Der1 der1 = (Der1) base; /* something */ } else if (base instanceof Der2) ...`

Comment: This involves changing the serialization algorithm each time there is a new subclass - which kind of sucks, right?

Comment: @JonasGröger The algorithm is the same regardless of what you are serializing.